# Edit text overlaps each other

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

I am creating an android application in which i am collecting user's some messages.But i am getting some issues such as following..

I have added 3 edit text in alert dialog..the third edit text box having multi line textbox so whenever i am adding multiple lines its getting overlapped to above two edit text

here is the snapshot of the error

[image: This one is perfect text]

[image: Here is issue]

**Here Is Layout file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:weightSum="1">
<ScrollView
android:layout_width="245dp"
android:layout_height="245dp"
android:layout_weight="0.40"
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="245dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp">
<EditText
    android:layout_width="235dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/editText6"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:hint="Your Email Id"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/editText5"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText5"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/editText4"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:hint="Title"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="236dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/editText5"
    android:hint="Description"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" /></RelativeLayout></ScrollView>

   <Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Submit"
    android:id="@+id/button10"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

 </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: use **android:layout_below="@+id/editText4"**, it will force the multiline textview to stay below the Description textview

Comment: Wrap your editText in a scrollView.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reason for your issue is `android:inputType="textMultiLine"` pushes content when there is a new line!

- You can use `android:maxLines="1"` for your `EditText`  [any way this will be useful for you since you have used  `android:singleLine="true"` with is kind of dipricated ]

**Ps**: Hard coding `android:maxLength` will not solve your issue since screens can be in different sizes which makes you hard to decide how many lines you keep!

Also you can use  `android:maxHeight="xdp"` for the `editText` view, then the limit won't exeed!

Comment: it will but i don't recommend you to do that. Lets say if you run that on a small screen just think it will be the same as now! I recommend you to use values based on ratios! or allocate size based on ratios which will be better!

Comment: @Nilesh Indalkar also i would like to point some changes you need! Still you dont have a clear idea about the weight sum please read this --> ask if you have a doubt  http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/android/94/layouts/11501/view-weight#t=201701281554004941051

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
android:maxLength="4"
```

row numbers you want to fix for your edit text

Comment: sorry but its allowed only 4 characters means 4 columns

Comment: yes it should have some fixed columns or else you will overlap of edit text.

Answer (score 0):

Use `LinearLayout` with vertical orientation instead of `RelativeLayout`.
If u want to use `RelativeLayout`, then set `layout_below` attribute of `RelativeLayout`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `android:maxLines="4"`. Set your max lines to solve this issue.

```
<EditText
android:id="@+id/editText4"
android:maxLines="4"
android:layout_width="240dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
android:hint="Title"
android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `android:layout_below` and `android:layout_marginTop` in your EditText views and keep distance between your views.

Example :

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="236dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/editText5"
    android:hint="Description"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"

    android:layout_below="@+id/editText4"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/>
```